# Getting attribute of type postgres

Tags: postgresql

lets say I create a type like this:

```
CREATE TYPE books AS (
  book_id NUMERIC
, row_num NUMERIC
);
```

I want to write a query that returns me the attributes (book_id, row_num) of books.

I am not sure how to do this?

Comment: I asked the question, and got an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56372111/getting-attribute-of-type-postgres#56372276

Comment: Please do [not crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/157328) - please delete this question here.